# Is there a way to do a "global inject" - i.e. inject the same set of services into every component class?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, blazor

I found myself injecting the same services into most of the components and retyping or copy-pasting a number of service inject declaration inside the classes that feels like a waste of time. Is there a way to do something similar to global @using with the DI service injections?

```
[Inject] NotificationService notificationService { get; set; } 
[Inject] DialogService dialogService { get; set; } 
[Inject] IJSRuntime jSRuntime { get; set; }    
[Inject] RegistrationService registrationService { get; set; }    
[Inject] NavigationManager navigationManager{ get; set; }    
[Inject] LocalStorageService localStorageService { get; set; }
```

For now, retyping all the service DI injections for each component. Would like to stop.

Comment: Personally, I'd just repeat them.  When you come back to old code a year from now, those extra lines you didn't want to type are going to make it crystal clear what you were up to.  Some of my "cleverest" solutions from the past have ended up giving me headaches later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a base class like this:

```cs
public class MyComponentBase : ComponentBase
{
    [Inject] private IJSRuntime jSRuntime { get; set; } = default!;
    [Inject] NavigationManager navigationManager { get; set; } = default!;

    //...
}
```

And then inherit all your components that need the service set.

You can also define a Transient Service that contains all your required services and the just inject that.

Comment: Of course! I don't know how I didn't think of a base class :) Thank you!